# Why starting WPF application from full screen program, minimizes the starter program?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winapi

I have an Windows x86 application written in Unity3D. I want to use Facebook OAUTH login from this desktop application. So i wrote a WPF application that is actually a webview. Everytime i started the WPF app from my main application, my application minimizes, and WPF app steals focus. So i tried making main app always on top, but this time WPF app doesn't come to foreground. Then i tried making WPF app always on top, it didn't work too.
Then i made WPF window's "ShowActivated" property to false. At first all things looks okay but when user clicks WPF app, main app minimizes and the WPF app gets focus.
So how can i solve this problem? Thank you for your helps.

**EDIT:** After Glen's comment i ran main application in windowed mode. This time WPF app didn't minimized main app and everything looked fine.But i need the main app in fullscren mode. So i hide the all window bars and made the app's resolution as same as screen resolution. It looks like fullscreen now and everything looks fine.
I viewed the keyboard's code by a .NET Reflector after Abin's comment. I didn't understand much how the program achieve to be top on a fullscren Directx application. For anyone who is in interest
[this is the keyboard program.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HuaaxHIEizT3hKLWpaT1RIVmM/view?usp=sharing)
So if you want to walkaround the problem you can make window borderless and fit to screen. But i don't think this is the actual answer. Actual answer should be .dll injection on Directx dll's or something.

Comment: I think this is because Unity uses DirectX and the DirectX application can't run in a non-fullscreen state and can't support having other applications laid over the top. It happens with any DirectX game I have used in the past, if I try to bring up another application on screen the game will minimize to the taskbar, if I activate the game again it will go fullscreen.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. But i have external keyboard program that is always on top, even in my Unity application. I don't know who is the owner of this program and i don't have source code so i can't figure out.

Comment: İ notice that keyboard application hides itself from "alt+tab" menu. Can be it is relative to problem?

Comment: Is  `external keyboard program `   .net compiled dll, Then you can use any tool like reflector to view the Code/XAML.

Comment: The actual answer is _never_ dll injection.  Why not make the interface using [unity's provided tools](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)? You can then handle the `UnityEvents` appropriately.